# ERROR in node_modules/@types/lodash/common/collection.d.ts(1783,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli, lodash

Whenever I try to run `ng serve` command getting the following error. Below is the error detail.

> ERROR in node_modules/@types/lodash/common/collection.d.ts(1783,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/collection.d.ts(1805,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/collection.d.ts(1827,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(818,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(827,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(837,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(848,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(853,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(870,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(878,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(887,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(897,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(902,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(916,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(924,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(933,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(943,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(948,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1689,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1706,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1723,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1740,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1817,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1841,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1865,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1874,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1898,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1974,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1998,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2022,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2046,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts(5,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'chart.js/src/chart.js'.

And Below is my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "TestApplication",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "angular-cli": {},
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200",
        "hmr": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 4201 --hmr -e=hmr",
        "test": "ng test",
        "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
        "e2e": "protractor"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.2.5",
        "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
        "@angular/common": "^5.2.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.5",
        "@angular/core": "^5.2.5",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.2.5",
        "@angular/http": "^5.2.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.5",
        "@angular/router": "^5.2.5",
        "@aspnet/signalr": "1.0.0-preview1-28189",
        "@durwella/zoomable-canvas": "^1.1.0",
        "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.33",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
        "@types/jquery.blockui": "0.0.28",
        "@types/jquery.validation": "^1.16.3",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.121",
        "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
        "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.34",
        "@types/signalr": "^2.2.33",
        "@types/toastr": "^2.1.33",
        "abp-ng2-module": "^2.0.0",
        "abp-web-resources": "^3.5.0",
        "adal-angular5": "^1.0.36",
        "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^2.9.0",
        "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
        "block-ui": "^2.70.1",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.2",
        "bootstrap-submenu": "^3.0.0",
        "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
        "flot": "^0.8.0-alpha",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jasmine": "^3.3.1",
        "jquery": "^3.1.1",
        "jquery-countto": "^1.2.0",
        "jquery-migrate": "^3.0.0",
        "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
        "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
        "js-cookie": "^2.1.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "moment": "^2.18.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
        "morris.js": "^0.5.0",
        "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
        "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.1",
        "ng2-search-filter": "^0.4.7",
        "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
        "ngx-debounce-click": "0.0.1",
        "ngx-image-zoom": "^0.3.3",
        "ngx-loading": "^2.0.1",
        "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.3",
        "ngx-pinch-zoom": "^1.2.0",
        "ngx-spinner": "6.1.2",
        "node-waves": "^0.7.5",
        "push.js": "1.0.4",
        "raphael": "^2.2.7",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
        "signalr": "^2.2.1",
        "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
        "spin.js": "^2.3.2",
        "sweetalert": "^2.0.8",
        "toastr": "^2.1.2",
        "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
        "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.6.8",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.5",
        "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^8.0.27",
        "codelyzer": "^3.1.2",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
        "karma": "^1.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
        "nswag": "^11.12.7",
        "protractor": "^5.1.1",
        "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
        "tslint": "^5.7.0",
        "typescript": "2.5.3"
    }
}
```

So far I tried:

1. npm install
2. changed the TypeScript version to 2.8
3. Deleted the node_modules and ran the npm install command
4. updated all the components to the latest version.

Any idea/suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

This resolved my issue...

1. Go to "\node_modules@types" in project repo.
2. and do 'npm i lodash'
3. Or use 'npm i -D @types/lodash@ts' to downgrade the version to make it compatible.

Comment: Respect man! You save my day

Answer (score 0):

According to this link at GitHub:

[error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/4225)

it seams that you may need to upgrade your TypeScript version or install a loadash compatible with your type script version ex:

```
npm i -D @types/lodash@ts2.5.3
```

Note: You mention TypeScript 2.8.3 but your package.json file still references TypeScript 2.5.3.